# increase md-autocomplete box width

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to increase the width of the md-autocomplete box, since some of the items that appear are not fully displayed (they end in "...").

Is there any way to change the width of md-autocomplete's dropdown box?

Comment: try adding .md-virtual-repeat-container.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container { right:0; } to your css. Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `md-menu-class="class-name"` attribute to your `<md-autocomplete>` tag
and give CSS to `class-name`

Please check the version of your angular-material and whether that version supports this feature or not.
If the above does not work. Try doing something like following. (Not recommended)

**CSS:**

```
.md-virtual-repeat-container.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container {
     width:700px !important;
}
```

This is working in your codepen. Please try this out.

Comment: Adding a class using md-menu-class helped, but the box still didn't increase when I added width: 500px.  Adding width helped a bit because it no longer has the '...'.  I think it increased the width of the textbox inside the dropdown, not the dropdown itself.  What CSS do I need to increase the dropdown width?

Comment: @McDonnas It has a max-width property set in angular-material.css as well.
in your css. Add the following 
max-width: 500px !important;

Comment: adding max-width: 500px !important didn't have an affect on the dropdown width. I even set max-width to 5000px and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @McDonnas A plunkr would really help me out. And also what is the version of angular-material, that you are using?

Comment: I am using version 0.11.0.  Here is a codepen of something very similar to my code.
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoLwJZ

Comment: @McDonnas I have updated my answer. This has been tested on your codepen only. Please check.

Comment: You need a combination of the two classes in order to get what want

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they fixed this issue, so you can just set the width of the md-autocomplete through css and everything else adjusts appropriately.

```
<md-autocomplete style="width: 22em;" ...
```

Comment: @jdgower bummer.  What version of material design are you using?